# Chaining promise with setTimeout

Tags: javascript

I have a "loading" animation that I'm attempting to hide, then I need to fade in and out some other text and buttons. The below code is what I have so far, but the code within the `then` function is executing before `hideLogoAnimation` finishes, which causes the rest of my elements to show and hide themselves in the incorrect order.

What am I doing wrong here?

Here is a codepen showing the issue:
https://codepen.io/TheNomadicAspie/pen/OJmzpXy

```
function handleWelcome(is_first_time = true) {
    console.log('handleWelcome')
    traceFunction()
    hideLogoAnimation().then(() => {
        hideInputText()
        console.log('handleWelcome is_first_time is ', is_first_time)
        hideButton(left_button)
        console.log('handleWelcome user_dict is ', user_dict)
        setTimeout(() => {
            if (is_first_time) {
                showInfo("Some words")
                showButton(right_button, 'Next', handleFirstTime1)
            } else {
                showInfo("Welcome back")
                showButton(right_button, 'Start', handleTestStart)
            }
        }, 250)
    })
}

function hideLogoAnimation() {
    console.log('hideLogoAnimation')
    return new Promise(() => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            logo_animation.classList.remove('fadein')
            logo_animation.classList.add('fadeout')
        }, 500)
        setTimeout(() => {
            logo_animation.classList.remove('show')
            speech_bubble_middle_bar.style.display = 'unset'
            speech_bubble_bottom_bar.style.display = 'grid'
            freeze_input = false
        }, 750)
    })
}
```

Comment: "*The code within the "then" function is executing*" - no it isn't, since you never resolve the promise that `hideLogoAnimation` returns. Please provide a [mcve], including all definitions of functions you are calling and a HTML page with the elements the code is using.

Comment: I put this codepen together to show the issue. Thank you.

https://codepen.io/TheNomadicAspie/pen/OJmzpXy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even your current solution will satisfy the use case, you can benefit from using animation libraries. The problem you encountered is already resolved by
**GSAP** https://greensock.com/gsap and **AnimeJS** https://animejs.com

The **Timeline** is what you're looking for to play the animation in sequence:
https://greensock.com/docs/v3/GSAP/Timeline
https://animejs.com/documentation/#timelineBasics

*Pros* for using animation libraries are:

1. They already solved many complex animation problems with performance in mind
2. They provide a standard way of animating things, so other developers don't have to learn your code but can use existing documentation

*Cons*:

1. You have to learn their API before using them
2. They are additional dependency to download (they're small, but still)

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm learning about GSAP now and this is exactly what I needed. Most of my time and my code is just sloppy manual animations. This is going to make my entire code so much cleaner. I'll be spending the next few days rewriting it all.

Answer (score 0):

In the Promise, you don't call resolve or reject callbacks to trigger then() or catch(), so in your case, you have to call resolve after adding/removing fadein/fadeout in setTimeout.